# Matching Array Elements in a Table and Returning Results in a New Field using clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with two fields, the first one, field "*path*", is a value and the second one, field "*arrKW*", is an array of strings.

```
+---------------------+----------------+
| path                | arrKW          |
+---------------------+----------------+
| folder/puntonet     | ['kw1','kw2'] |
| folder/puntonet-2.0 | ['kw2','kw3']  |
| folder/puntonet-4   | ['kw2','kw4'] |
| folder/puntonet-5   | ['kw5','kw4']  |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to obtain, for each field "*path*", an array of elements where there is a match with any element from field "*arrKW*",but not including the same value as in field "*path*".

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| path                | arrKW               | Result Field                                |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| folder/puntonet     | ['kw1','kw2']      | ['folder/puntonet-2.0','folder/puntonet-4'] |
| folder/puntonet-2.0 | ['kw2','kw3','kw5'] | ['folder/puntonet','folder/puntonet-5']     |
| folder/puntonet-4   | ['kw2','kw4']      | ['folder/puntonet','folder/puntonet-2.0']   |
| folder/puntonet-5   | ['kw5','kw4']       | ['folder/puntonet-2.0','folder/puntonet-4'] |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why it's became ['kw2','kw3','kw5'] ? I am missing the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in the question does not match to the description.

```sql
create table test (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/puntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/puntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw3']),
('folder/puntonet-4',['kw2','kw4']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']));

SELECT
    (arrayJoin(a) AS t).2 AS path,
    t.1 AS KW,
    arrayFilter(i -> (i != path), groupArrayArray(patha)) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        groupArray(path) AS patha,
        groupArray((arrKW, path)) AS a,
        arrayJoin(arrKW) AS KW
    FROM test
    GROUP BY KW
)
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY path ASC

┌─path────────────────┬─KW────────────┬─result────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ folder/puntonet     │ ['kw1','kw2'] │ ['folder/puntonet-2.0','folder/puntonet-4']                   │
│ folder/puntonet-2.0 │ ['kw2','kw3'] │ ['folder/puntonet','folder/puntonet-4']                       │
│ folder/puntonet-4   │ ['kw2','kw4'] │ ['folder/puntonet','folder/puntonet-2.0','folder/puntonet-5'] │
│ folder/puntonet-5   │ ['kw5','kw4'] │ ['folder/puntonet-4']                                         │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry @Denny other doubt... if instead of having only one table, there were two tables that share both fields, 'path' and 'arrKW', how could I add the values from the 'path' field of table 2 for all the fields where there is a match for any value of the 'arrKW' field of both tables?

```
create table test (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/puntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/puntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw3']),
('folder/puntonet-4',['kw2','kw4']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']));

create table test2 (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/otherpuntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-4',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']));
```

Result desired

```
| path                 | arrKW         | arrResult                                                                                        |
+----------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| folder/otherpuntonet | ['kw1','kw2'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                                            |
| folder/puntonet-2.0  | ['kw2','kw3'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                     |
| folder/puntonet-4    | ['kw2','kw4'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4','folder/puntonet-5'] |
| folder/puntonet-5    | ['kw5','kw4'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet-4']                                                                       |
```

Comment: Ask another (new) question